# Basic Authentication not working in python

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am implementing basic authentication to validate username and password with the following code:

```
def auth_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        auth = request.authorization
        cur = get_db().cursor().execute("SELECT * FROM users where user_name='parag'")
        result = cur.fetchall()
        if auth and auth.username == result[0][user_name] and auth.password== result[0][password]:
            return True
        return make_response('could not verify', 401, {'WWW-authenticate' : 'Basic realm = "Login Required"'})
    return decorated

@app.route("/")
@auth_required
def index():
    data = request.get_json()
    cur = get_db().cursor())
    return '''<h1> hi paarg </h1>'''
```

but auth.username and auth.password is none. 
auth = request.authorization is coming as a NoneType.
Please help.

Comment: Just wondering, is there a reason you are using @basic_auth.required while the decorator function is called auth_required

Comment: @gittert thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have edited the code. Now you can see it what is wrong in it.

Comment: There is a flask snippet that does a similar thing (or you can use something like flask-login which has built in decorators for this purpose). See http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/. I cannot test your code but I think there is somethign going wrong in your database query. you should check the output of that query first to debug the issue.